Blazor server - file upload
When trying to upload the same image using the following code, it is successful sometimes and gives following error at other times. I referenced following but no success https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0
The error occurs at code line -- await browserFile.OpenReadStream(5 * 1024 * 1024).CopyToAsync(fs);
Error Message:
System.InvalidOperationException: Concurrent reads or writes are not supported. at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetFlushResult(FlushResult& result) at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetFlushAsyncResult() at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeWriter.GetResult(Int16 token) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSDataStream.ReceiveData(Int64 chunkId, Byte[] chunk, String error) at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result) at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult() at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeReaderStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSDataStream.ReadAsync(Memory1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.CopyFileDataIntoBuffer(Int64 sourceOffset, Memory1 destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.ReadAsync(Memory1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.IO.Stream.g__Core|29_0(Stream source, Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
private async Task UploadImage(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var browserFile = e.File;
    var path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    await using FileStream fs = new(path, FileMode.Create);
    await browserFile.OpenReadStream(5 * 1024 * 1024).CopyToAsync(fs);
}

<InputFile OnChange="UploadImage" accept="image/*" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />


I mean, you posted the documentation link. Why aren't you using the recommended method as shown? You shouldn't be using memory stream, it is potentially vulnerable.

Hi Adam, although both codes were same but now make it clear I have updated code to resemble it exactly with the solution provided on official Microsoft website. The error still occurs at code line -- await browserFile.OpenReadStream(5 * 1024 * 1024).CopyToAsync(fs);

After searching online I found and used the following solution - https://github.com/Tewr/BlazorFileReader
This is working fine.
Although the documentation of this solution says that one shud use Microsoft provided blazor element InputFile, but that doesn't work for my straightforward requirement of uploading a 100KB-1000KB file

I am having an issue while uploading multiple images with Blazor Server .net8; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78816542/blazor-server-net-8-multiple-image-upload-problem
