Blazor Server .NET 8 multiple image upload problem
I am trying to upload multiple images, but getting this weird error while uploading the second image whatever I tried I couldn't manage.
Here is my razor page method which gets the images:
private async Task HandleImageUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    IsLoading = true;
    try
    {
        var files = e.GetMultipleFiles();

        var validFiles = new List<IBrowserFile>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(file.Name);
            if (fileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".jpg" ||
                fileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".png" ||
                fileInfo.Extension.ToLower() == ".jpeg")
            {
                validFiles.Add(file);
            }
            else
            {
                await _jsRuntime.ToastrError("Please select .jpg/.jpeg/.png file only");
                IsLoading = false;
                return;
            }
        }

        var imageUrls = await _fileUpload.UploadFiles(validFiles);
        Product.ImageUrls.AddRange(imageUrls);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await _jsRuntime.ToastrError(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsLoading = false;
    }
}

Here is the service I am trying to upload images:
public async Task<List<string>> UploadFiles(IEnumerable<IBrowserFile> files)
{
    var filePaths = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var fullPath = "";
            FileInfo fileInfo = new(file.Name);
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileInfo.Extension;
            var folderDirectory = $"{_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\images\\product";

            if (!Directory.Exists(folderDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderDirectory);
            }

            var filePath = Path.Combine(folderDirectory, fileName);

            await using var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            await file.OpenReadStream(MaxFileSize).CopyToAsync(fs);

            fullPath = $"/images/product/{fileName}";
            filePaths.Add(fullPath);
        }

        return filePaths;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}

Max file size is 30MB and the images I am trying to upload are 2MB total.

Here is the weird error I am getting:
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=e is null
Qe@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:37025
readFileData@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:36985
beginInvokeJSFromDotNet/s<@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3047
beginInvokeJSFromDotNet@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3004
_invokeClientMethod@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:60890
_processIncomingData@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:58279
Xt/this.connection.onreceive@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:51920
connect/</s.onmessage@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:80026

  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.<OpenReadStreamAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.<CopyFileDataIntoBuffer>d__30.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.<ReadAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
   at System.IO.Stream.<<CopyToAsync>g__Core|27_0>d.MoveNext()
   at Web_Server.Service.FileUpload.<UploadFiles>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\197199\Desktop\E-Commerce\Blazor-master\Web_Server\Service\FileUpload.cs:line 93

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    Web_Server.Service.FileUpload.UploadFiles(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.IBrowserFile>) in FileUpload.cs

I searched but couldn't find a way to fix this issue. Hope you guys can help me.
Note: It was a .net6 Blazor Server application, I changed it target framework to .net8.
Update:
I added "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR": "Debug" to appsettings.Development.json.
Added HubOptions to Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    hubOptions.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 20;
});

Here is the SignalR message I am getting:
Uploading file: jpeg-optimizer_s-l1602-removebg-preview.png, Size: 5048, Path: C:\Users\197199\Desktop\E-Commerce\TangyBlazor-master\TangyWeb_Server\wwwroot\images\product\d4274f9e-b04b-435d-9773-5bc9b4af57ed.png
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "", Target: "EndInvokeJSFromDotNet", Arguments: [ 108, True, [108,true,{"__jsStreamReferenceLength":5048,"__jsObjectId":1}] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "", Target: "EndInvokeJSFromDotNet", Arguments: [ 109, True, [109,true,null] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "", Target: "EndInvokeJSFromDotNet", Arguments: [ 110, True, [110,true,null] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "", Target: "EndInvokeJSFromDotNet", Arguments: [ 111, True, [111,true,null] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "", Target: "EndInvokeJSFromDotNet", Arguments: [ 112, True, [112,true,null] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "", Target: "OnRenderCompleted", Arguments: [ 16,  ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "", Target: "EndInvokeJSFromDotNet", Arguments: [ 113, True, [113,true,null] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "", Target: "ReceiveJSDataChunk", Arguments: [ 0, 0, System.Byte[],  ], StreamIds: [  ] }.
Uploading file: jpeg-optimizer_s-l1603-removebg-preview.png, Size: 7382, Path: C:\Users\197199\Desktop\E-Commerce\TangyBlazor-master\TangyWeb_Server\wwwroot\images\product\9e2d026c-43b1-4f34-96c4-4b44d9127e9a.png
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher[1]
      Received hub invocation: InvocationMessage { InvocationId: "", Target: "EndInvokeJSFromDotNet", Arguments: [ 114, False, [114,false,"e is null\nQe@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:37025\nreadFileData@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:36985\nbeginInvokeJSFromDotNet/s<@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3047\nbeginInvokeJSFromDotNet@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:3004\n_invokeClientMethod@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:60890\n_processIncomingData@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:58279\nXt/this.connection.onreceive@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:51920\nconnect/</s.onmessage@http://localhost:7253/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:80026\n"] ], StreamIds: [  ] }.

Update 2:
My project is Blazor Server, not Blazor Web App and the target framework is .net 8. Maybe it is due to render mode. How can I add InteractiveServerRenderMode?

Looks like it's a JSInterop exception but why are you using JavaScript for this?

I am not using javascript, thats why it's so weird.

you can't get what you need from inputchangedevent.  You should simply trigger submit on the form if you want to upload the files when the change happens.  (that is JS running on frontend...)  Easier to validate the extensions by setting "accept" attribute of <input type="file"...

I think IBrowserFile is all local and client-side.  So this isn't really an upload, but saving a copy client-side.  "Note that Blazor apps executing code on the server aren't able to access the client's file system directly.":  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#file-uploads  You really never want to process file's client-side for upload... (it's slower as it will create a copy)

also be sure not to rely on client-side validations.  Make sure you validate properly on server-side too.  (be in full control of filename/extension as this will be untrusted user-input... )

I will try <input type="file"... and let you know, hope you are right.

After a lot of trial and error and tears the following code worked interestingly. I put this method on the razor page, not on the service.
//Remove old images
Product.ImageUrls.Clear();

foreach (var file in _selectedFiles)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new(file.Name);
    var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileInfo.Extension;
    var folderDirectory = $"{_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\images\\product";

    if (!Directory.Exists(folderDirectory))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderDirectory);
    }

    var filePath = Path.Combine(folderDirectory, fileName);

    Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream();
    FileStream fs = File.Create(filePath);
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
    stream.Close();
    fs.Close();

    _fullPath = $"/images/product/{fileName}";
    Product.ImageUrls.Add(_fullPath);
}

